# What HTML5 Canvas Pixel Detection and image manipulation libraries are out there?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to develop a "Web App" (for lack of better terminology) that displays a sort of interactive map using the HTML5 Canvas element for mobile devices. The map has about 30 buildings (made from semi-transparent PNG images on it) of different shapes and sizes. I want the user to be able to tap on any of the buildings to get information about them. The buildings are often within the same theoretical bounding box of others, so it isn't as simple as just detecting when the user taps in a bounding box (imagine a U shaped building with another building inside the U). Therefore, it should use some sort of raster pixel detection. To make matters more complicated, I need to allow the user to zoom in/out and pan around on the map (because 30 buildings and a map are way too much to show a user on a tiny cellphone screen). So scaling and moving smoothly is a necessity.

I am looking for a JavaScript library that can support these functions:

1. Image pixel detection
2. Mobile touch events
3. Canvas (or stage?) scaling
4. Usable on mobile devices

So far, I have found KineticJS which supports all of these features. But when I try to move the map with more than 4 buildings on the stage, it is way too jumpy. I tried checking into Fabric.js but it doesn't seem to have pixel detection (as it selects the image when you click within the bounding box, not the actual image itself).

Is there any other JavaScript library out there that can do these things?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The KineticJS is pretty good ( the best lib i found so far )

I never tried to use png images with it, but zooming and panning with a few hundreds primitive objects is pretty smooth (without pixel detection - I imagine the pixel detection is quite cpu expensive operation ).

Maybe you could try overlay standard polygons ( a few for one building ) and attach to the same click/tap event.

Also you don't necessary need to move objects on the canvas you can just put bigger canvas in smaller div ( with overflow:hidden) and drag the whole canvas element.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I tried a couple options pertaining to your answer and they didn't seem to work. I was going to try the polygon solution, but rendering all of the PNGs seems to be the problem even when I took pixel detection off. Putting the canvas inside of another DIV won't work because it would have to re-render on zoom in and zoom out to increase the clarity and the re-render, not surprisingly, is just as bad as moving them all.
I think this might just be pushing the device too far in Javascript and HTML. I was hoping there might be another library out there to try.

Comment: Regarding slow map moving, did you try to set for the stage the draggable attribute to true?